# Truffle/Ganache: is there a way to set a deployment address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

I'm currently developing a dapp in Solidity and want to frequently test it locally along with the updates - so I don't really want to redeploy it everytime to a test net.
However, everytime I deploy it, the address the smart contract is deployed to changes, so I have to update my front-end code to the new address.

Is there a way to "force" the smart contract to always be deployed  at the same address? Or is there any other equivalent solution you might think of?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI https://blog.zeppelinos.org/proxy-patterns/

Comment: It is interesting, but it does not really help me in my case... Unless I missed something?

Comment: Have you ever found a way to set the contract address at deployment time?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. I don't know whether it legal but you can do:

> in your migration file (*migrations/1_example_migration.js*)

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    console.log(deployer);
    console.log(arguments);
    let n = 5; // it can be any address from list of available
    deployer.deploy(MyContract, {from: arguments[2][n]});
};
```

[Documentation](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the account list you have by passing in the accounts argument like [follows](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#available-accounts) In the `deploy_migration` files :

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  // Use the accounts within your migrations.
}
```